# How do I resolve Syntax error 'for' is not matched?

Tags: shell

I have little scripting experience.  I have tried a new script to loop through multiple subdirectories and edit a file if the subdirectory exists.  Here is the code I've failed with after multiple attempts, but I cannot resolve the for loop error:

---

```
!#/usr/din/sh

for domain in {PGBWAHS_NA PGBWAHS04_NA PGBWAHD_NA PGBWAHD04_NA PGBWAHQ_NA PGBWAHQ02_NA PGBWAHQ03_NA PGBWAHQ04_NA PGBWAHP_NA PGBWAHP02_NA PGBWAHP03_NA PGBWAHP04_NA

do

 echo "$domain this is the current domain from the array"

  cd /opt/tibco/tra/domain/$domain

   echo `pwd` "this is the directory after cd command"

   cp hawkagent.cfg hawkagent.cfg.back

  sed 's/-scan_rate 10/-scan_rate 30/' hawkagent.cfg

Done
____________________
Error message returned:
$ ./modify_log_scan_rate.sh
./modify_log_scan_rate.sh[3]: Syntax error at line 3 : `for' is not matched.
```

Comment: Your shebang line is a mess. The format is `#!/path/to/binary`. Also I'm assuming `din` there is a typo for `bin`? What shell is running this? What shell is *supposed* to be running this? `Done` needs to be `done` (case matters).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the opening curly braces after in: **for domain in *{*PGBWAHS_NA ...**

Comment: While it is true that that likely isn't correct as written here (that was probably an attempt at brace expansion or soemthing) that isn't the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

`Done` needs to be `done` (case matters).
                    – Etan Reisner